# AngularJS - Trouble with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's the data I'm working with:

```
$scope.products = [
{
  'id': 643,
  'name': 'Product Name',
  'applications': [
    {
      'id': 100,
      'name': 'Adobe After Effects CC (2014)',
      'gfx': [
        {
          'id': 514,
          'name': 'Graphics AE Test 1'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'id': 101,
      'name': 'Adobe Premiere Pro CC (2014)',
      'gfx': [
        {
          'id': 514,
          'name': 'Graphics AP Test 1'
        },
        {
          'id': 512,
          'name': 'Graphics AP Test 2'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
 }
];
```

What i'm trying to do is loop through all of the graphics card for a specific application.  You choose the application via a dropdown, and I have the selected application in a variable `{{ scope.selectedApplication }}`.  So with that, here's what I have tried:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="driver in result.applications | filter: { name: selectedApplication } track by $index">
    <td>{{ driver.gfx[$index].name }}</td>
</tr>
```

So this is somewhat working, just not exactly how I want. The filter is filtering it down to the correct application, which works fine. The problem I am having is that `driver.gfx[$index].name` is only showing the first result. Since I am looping through applications instead of gfx, the `$index` isn't going to work for me.

How can I loop through the graphics cards after my initial ng-repeat? It seems like I need two statements, but how would that work?

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have nested hg-repeat if you like to have a nested table.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="driver in result.applications | filter: { name: selectedApplication } track by $index">
    <td>  
       <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in driver.gfx">
          <td >
            {{item.name}}
          <td/>
       </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

if you want to have single denormalized table, one option would be to create a function that does the denormalization and then use result of that function in a normal hg-repeat.

The other option would be having multiple tbody. so your outer loop occurs on tbody and inner loop on row

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="driver in result.applications | filter: { name: selectedApplication } track by $index">
        <tr ng-repeat="item in driver.gfx">
          <td >
            {{item.name}}
          <td/>
       </tr>
</tbody>
```

and finally you can have some rows that either style them as separators or just hide them by CSS and use ng-repeat-start and hg-repeat-end like this

```
<table>
<tr class="separator" data-ng-repeat-start="driver in result.applications | filter: { name: selectedApplication } track by $index"><td></td></tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="item in driver.gfx">
          <td >
            {{item.name}}
          <td/>
       </tr>

<tr class="seperator" ng-repeat-end><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This would give me W541 AP Test 1W541 AP Test 2 inside of my <td> when I actually need a whole new table row for each driver.

Comment: ok, do you want nested table or just rows in the parent table?

Comment: @Braim, from comment above: _new table row_

Comment: Tried to list all possible solutions

Comment: Thanks a lot Braim.  I went with the second solution, where the first loop is on the <tbody>.  Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need another ng-repeat that loops through each `gfx`.

```
<td>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="gfx in driver.gfx">{{ gfx.name }}</li>
</ul>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the selected application is set via a binding of `{{ selectedApplication }}` ($scope is implied), then your ng-repeat should look like:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="driver in selectedApplication | filter: { name: selectedApplication } track by $index">
    <td>{{ driver.gfx[$index].name }}</td>
</tr>
```

This means you'll be talking about the *driver* inside the selected application object.